# rlwrap-like tool with command autocompletion

Tags: command-line, autocomplete, sqlite

I am often using `rlwrap sqlite database.sqlite` to browse an SQLite table. It works great but I would like to have a tool that would create an index tables (and possible its columns as well) and let me autocomplete them using `<TAB>`.

Is there any such tool or should I create it by my own? Should I then write extension for `rlwrap`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9219349/4941495

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty way to achieve what you want is to use `rlwrap` with the `--remember` (or `-r`) option:

```
  -r, --remember
          Put all words seen on in- and output on the completion list.
```

After starting `sqlite` with:

```
$ rlwrap -r sqlite database.sqlite
```

make `sqlite` print all table and field names by issuing the meta-command  `.fullschema` (or, with even less typing, put this command in a file `init` and then run `rlwrap -r sqlite -init init database.sqlite`)

You will then be able to autocomplete on those names with the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.